# Migrate IIS Applications from Windows Server 2003 to 2012

Tags: iis-7.5, iis-6, windows-server-2003, windows-server-2012, server-migration

I have a Windows Server 2003 SP2 that is running IIS 6 with several web sites and Web applications and I need to copy the all the web sites and web applications to a Windows Server 2012 server running IIS 7.5. Is there anyway to copy the all the application to the new server?

Comment: Microsoft has Web Deploy tool for you.

Answer (score 1):

There is a tool called the Web Deployment Tool.  It's a command tool.  Below is a technet article all about this.

The process is pretty simple and only takes ~10 minutes for your average site or application.

To start, make backups of your existing IIS6 and IIS7 sites/applications and configs.  Next, find any components that are required by your sites/applications and install those on your destination server.  There is a command in the tool that lists dependencies.  Then you pre-test the deployment and finally you execute.

Good luck.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff633422%28v=ws.10%29.aspx

Comment: Thanks, Is there any other tool available for migration?

Comment: That's the only tool I know about.